# Why is it slow when deleting features in gpkg using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, features, performance, geopackage, delete

Deleting features in a somewhat big GeoPackage takes a really long time and I am not sure if I do something wrong or if it is normal that it takes such a long time.

Data: line GeoPackage layer containing ~20 Million entities (~9GB)

Entities are deleted this way:

```py
layer.dataProvider().deleteFeatures(ids)
```

Deleting around 15 Million entities takes over a half hour, while doing so the `*.gpkg-wal` grows about 1-2 MB/s until it reaches about 90% of the size of the `*.gpkg`.

Which makes it faster to create a copy of the layer in memory, delete in memory and then export to a new GeoPackage file. But that is REALLY not ideal in terms of ram and disk space.

Is there a faster/better way to update a large GeoPackage?

Edit performance multiple smaller transactions vs one bigger transaction (deleting 500,000 entities out of a layer containing 1,000,000 entities):

```
def setup():
    shutil.copy2(r"C:\experiments\example-backup.gpkg", r"C:\experiments\example.gpkg")
    global layer
    layer = QgsVectorLayer(r"C:\experiments\example.gpkg", "example", "ogr")
    ids = random.sample([f.id() for f in layer.getFeatures()], 500000)
    return layer, ids

def teardown():
    global layer
    del layer
    os.remove(r"C:\experiments\example.gpkg")


# wal file grows to full size of gpkg : 313 MB
layer, ids = setup()
with Timer.context("update by dataprovider"):
    layer.dataProvider().deleteFeatures(ids)
teardown()

# wal file grows to : 77MB
layer, ids = setup()
for sub_ids in [ids[x:x + 10000] for x in range(0, 500000, 10000)]:
    with Timer.context("update by dataprovider splitted (50)"):
            layer.dataProvider().deleteFeatures(sub_ids)
teardown()

# wal file grows to : 8MB
layer, ids = setup()
for sub_ids in [ids[x:x+500] for x in range(0, 500000, 500)]:
    with Timer.context("update by dataprovider splitted (1000)"):
        layer.dataProvider().deleteFeatures(sub_ids)
teardown()

layer, ids = setup()
with Timer.context("update by edit block"):
    with edit(layer):
        layer.deleteFeatures(ids)
teardown()

layer, ids = setup()
with edit(layer):
    for sub_ids in [ids[x:x + 10000] for x in range(0, 500000, 10000)]:
        with Timer.context("update by edit block splitted (50)"):
            layer.deleteFeatures(sub_ids)
            layer.commitChanges(stopEditing=False)
teardown()

layer, ids = setup()
with edit(layer):
    for sub_ids in [ids[x:x + 500] for x in range(0, 500000, 500)]:
        with Timer.context("update by edit block splitted (1000)"):
            layer.deleteFeatures(sub_ids)
            layer.commitChanges(stopEditing=False)
teardown()

print(Timer.get_formatted())
```

result:

```
update by dataprovider -> 36.247s (calls: 1, average time : 36.247s)
update by dataprovider splitted (50) -> 1m 14s (calls: 50, average time : 1.499s)
update by dataprovider splitted (1000) -> 2m 22s (calls: 1000, average time : 142.593ms)
update by edit block -> 32.201s (calls: 1, average time : 32.201s)
update by edit block splitted (50) -> 1m 20s (calls: 50, average time : 1.610s)
update by edit block splitted (1000) -> 3m 6s (calls: 1000, average time : 186.321ms)
```

result bis (doing the same thing but deleting 500,000 entities out of a layer of 20,000,000 entities)

```
update by dataprovider -> 1m 29s (calls: 1, average time : 1m 29s)
update by dataprovider splitted (50) -> 2m 17s (calls: 50, average time : 2.754s)
update by dataprovider splitted (1000) -> 2m 50s (calls: 1000, average time : 170.291ms)
update by edit block -> 1m 31s (calls: 1, average time : 1m 31s)
update by edit block splitted (50) -> 2m 25s (calls: 50, average time : 2.913s)
update by edit block splitted (1000) -> 3m 33s (calls: 1000, average time : 213.331ms)
```

Looks like less transactions is better which makes sense because most of the time is spent writing the wal file. Having more transactions means checking the state (and depending also deleting) the wal file more often so it is slower.

So the question remains how can I make this faster? Without going with a memory layer.

Btw, the same thing on using a Shapefile layer gives me:

```
update by dataprovider -> 8.747s (calls: 1, average time : 8.747s)
update by dataprovider splitted (50) -> 6m 30s (calls: 50, average time : 7.815s)
# It rewrites the entire file(s) each time 
# so doing 50 smaller updates takes ~50 times longer 
# than one big update
```

So much faster on single "transaction" even though all I have read seems to say that GeoPackage is much faster than ShapeFile.

Comment: does the geopackage driver provide any way to control transactions? it sounds as if it is doing the everything in one transaction, so using smaller groups of IDs may be faster

Comment: Are you using a for loop to get `ids`?

Comment: @PyMapr No, I made sure it is an already created list.

Comment: A GPKG is just a glorified SQLITE database file. The WAL file is a data log of the transactional state of the database for COMMIT's and or ROLLBACK's. This [link](https://sqlite.org/wal.html#avoiding_excessively_large_wal_files) explains why the WAL file grows so big. As for why it's so slow I'm not 100% and could be due to a few variables (hardware and/or software related).

Comment: One potential reason could be due to "3. Disk I/O operations tends to be more sequential using WAL." under [overview](https://sqlite.org/wal.html#overview).

Comment: @PyMapr I don't think I have any hardware issues, My work laptop is only a couple of years old and pretty good. I will try to split my update into smaller transactions. And also check if it is actually I/O bound or not.

Comment: Well it's definitly I/O bound because of the wal file, but I have no idea if/how it is possible to change the behavior of the provider to change that

Comment: Which QGIS and GDAL version are you using?

Comment: @bugmenot123 QGIS version: 3.22.11-Białowieża ; 
GDAL/OGR version 3.5.1

Comment: This seems more suited as a bug report to QGIS. No idea what their transaction size is.

Comment: Your benchmarks are not really intuitive to understand, is the average time the average time for a full run of the deletion? If so, it seems like you found a solution by splitting the deletion into smaller parts.